# PhpStorm REST Client connection error

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, phpstorm

I am doing an API test using the REST Client in PhpStorm, but I am currently holding my ankle due to this error:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

How do I resolve this error? And why is it happening?

If you have experienced this problem or have solved it, let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no server listening on port 8080 for the PHPStorm REST client to connect to.

You probably want to enable and configure [PHPStorm's internal web server](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/php-built-in-web-server.html).

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: You should configure a web server (PHPStorm has one) so that it serves requests on localhost, port 8080, using - I suppose - your PHP files.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to resolve this issue.

In the **Host/Port** field, put this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/your_project_root_name
```

For the **Path**, put your endpoint. For example:

```
/users
```

Hope this helps anyone else!